# Sorting class with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I created jQuery sorter plugin like below to filter by classes.  But now I am not sure how to only display `class="apple"` by default.  Right now when I reload the page both APPLE and TREE is visible.

```
<ul>
  <li class="apple">APPLE</li>
  <li class="tree">TREE</li>
  <li class="apple tree">ALL</li>
</ul>

<div>
  <div class="apple">APPLE</div>
  <div class="tree">TREE</div>
  <div class="apple">APPLE</div>
  <div class="tree">TREE</div>
  <div class="apple">APPLE</div>
  <div class="tree">TREE</div>
</div>

<script src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("ul li").click(function() {
  visibleClasses = $(this).attr("class").split(" ");
  $("div div").hide(); // or slideUp / fadeOut
  for(i in visibleClasses) {
    $("div div."+visibleClasses[i]).fadeIn(500); // or slideDown / show
  }
});
</script>
```

Comment: FYI, it's not a safe practice to iterate an array with `for(i in visibleClasses)` both because `i` is an implicit global variable and because you shouldn't use `for(x in y)` to iterate arrays (because it also iterates properties).  You should do it like this:  `for (var i = 0; i < visibleClasses.length; i++)` and you should use `var` on your local variables so they aren't implicit globals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hide all non-apples with:

```
$("div div:not(.apple)").hide();
```

Rather than iterate the array, construct a selector that get's all the elements at once:

```
var selector = "div div." + visibleClasses.join(",div div.");
```

`selector` will contain `"div div.apple,div div.tree"` which will select elements that match either of the comma separated selectors.  You can then do:

```
$(selector).fadeIn(500);
```

**Edit:** So, with this change, your code would look like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
    $(function () {
        $("div div:not(.apple)").hide();
        $("ul li").click(function() {
            var visibleClasses = $(this).attr("class").split(" ");
            $("div div").hide();
            var selector = "div div." + visibleClasses.join(",div div.");
            $(selector).fadeIn(500);
        });
    });
</script>
```

---

By, the way, if you choose to iterate the Array use a regular `for` loop or [`Array.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).  [Do not use `for..in` to iterate an Array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4261096/361684).  The `for..in` statement is for *enumerating*, not *iterating*.

Comment: Thank you for the tip but I am new to javascript and still learning.  How would I implement this in my code?

Answer (score 1):

Add this to the end of your script:

```
$("div div").hide();
$("div div.apple").show();
```